# Sending HTML email through Google Groups

Tags: email, pdf, html, google-groups

I want to send a formatted email (say HTML or PDF) to a large group of people (all parents in a school - no, I do not mean to spam, just send them a monthly newsletter about school-related activities).

[Google Groups help](http://groups.google.com/group/managing-your-group/browse_thread/thread/515ec8255e137828/9e3de2ee8540dac6?lnk=gst&q=) says that I can open a group large enough.

However, [this FAQ](http://sites.google.com/site/tomihasa/google-groups-faq#htmlinmessages) says I cannot send HTML email from Google Groups.
As I do not want to send HTML or PDF as attachments but rather as the message itself,
do you know of a way to do this in Google Groups, or a competing site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no way you can do that in Google Groups.

It is not possible even in Yahoo! Groups.

HTML and pdf files have to be sent as attachment even in GMail and all the e-mail services.

At the best, what you can do is upload the pdf or html file to Google Docs/Google Drive or some similar service and share a link to it in the message.

Answer (score 1):

HTML messages can be sent to Google groups using a desktop app called MaxBulk Mailer ([www.maxprog.com](https://www.maxprog.com/)). I've been doing this for several years, sending a monthly report to our not for profit membership.

The only issue I've had is that I am not able to send to our group 'from' our Google Workspace account. Google considers the sender to be spoofed. I have to use another mail server.

Answer (score 0):

Google restricts more on group topic. In Gmail you can make html email but restricted to send to less than 20 recipients of contact group per email.